# Configuring postfix to use TLS for a particular server?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, starttls

Running kubuntu 10.04 on my host, let's call it `alpha`.  I've got postfix as my system MTA.  I've got crons running on `alpha` that need to send email to a remote host, let's call it `mailhost`.  I cannot alter any configs on `mailhost`.

Normally I use Thunderbird to send/get email through `mailhost` using IMAP over TLS.  The SMTP setup in Thunderbird is configured to use STARTTLS.

I want cron jobs running on `alpha` to send mail to `mailhost`, but because `alpha` is a dynamic-IP host behind residential NAT, it's difficult to get `mailhost` to accept mail from `alpha` due to the usual anti-spam/RBL heuristics.  However, if I can get postfix to use TLS to connect to `mailhost` when it's sending mail to an address (`dirtside@mailhost` for example), then the mails should go through just fine.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to configure postfix to use STARTTLS with a specific username and password ONLY when connecting to `mailhost`.

Alternative solutions (e.g. using something besides postfix) are acceptable, but the ultimate task is still to allow crons running on `alpha` to send emails to `dirtside@mailhost.com`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [smtp_tls_policy_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_tls_policy_maps) to configure the TLS policy on a per host basis.

`main.cf`:

```
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
```

`/etc/postfix/tls_policy`:

```
mailhost.com    encrypt
```

Remember to run `postmap /etc/postfix/tls_policy` after editing that file.

You could also set `smtp_tls_security_level = may` to use TLS when the remote server supports it, but fallback to non-TLS otherwise.